# awaiting ContinueWith result does not wait for the task to complete

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have the following  minimal code :

```
class Program
{
    static async Task T1()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("T1");
    }
    static async Task T2()
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        Console.WriteLine("T2");
    }
    static async Task Test()
    {
        var firstTask = T1();
        var secondTask = firstTask.ContinueWith(async (t) => await T2());

        await secondTask;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async () => { await Test(); }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("End");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I excepected that Test method will wait for the T2 to complete, but I got the following result

```
T1
End
T2
```

Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `Unwrap` method.

If you look at the type of `secondTask`, you'll see that's it's actually a `Task<Task>`, so while you're awaiting the outer task, the inner task is not blocking. The way to handle this when nesting async calls is as follows:

```
var secondTask = firstTask.ContinueWith(async (t) => await T2()).Unwrap();
```

`secondTask` is now of type `Task`, and you should see the behavior you expect.